# Android: Scaled bitmap and texts on canvas with proper x and y positions and scaleX and scaleY factors

Tags: android, android-view, android-canvas, android-bitmap

We are working on the android application where a user can upload texts and images, drag and drop it anywhere on the screen, zoom in and out on it, and then save it as a pdf.

When we upload an image or text, we are storing few data in the firebase: x position by `view.x`, y position by `view.y`, scaleX by `view.scaleX` and scaleY by `view.scaleY`. If it is an image, then the url of the image as a `data` field and if it is a text, then the text string as a `data` field.

**Uploaded on the device:**

[image: Uploaded on the device]

Later, we are left with these values only and no actual views. We need to use these values to create a pdf similar to what it was at the time of uploading images and texts.

At the time of saving it as a pdf, we are taking a canvas, using these values, convert it into a pdf.

We are getting all the data in the generated and saved pdf but position and scale factors are totally improper.

**After saving it as a pdf:**

[image: Saved pdf]

Below is the code using which we are drawing bitmap on the canvas:

**Bitmap on the canvas**

```
private suspend fun drawBitmapOnCanvas(
        canvas: Canvas,
        uriStringPath: String,
        boardSketch: BoardSketch? = null
    ) {
        if (uriStringPath.isEmpty()) {
            return
        } else {
            return suspendCoroutine {
                var xLeft = 0f
                var yTop = 0f
                var scaleX = 1F
                var scaleY = 1F

                boardSketch?.matrix?.let { matrix ->
                    scaleX = matrix[2]
                    scaleY = matrix[3]
                }

                Glide.with(this)
                    .asBitmap()
                    .load(uriStringPath)
                    .into(object : CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
                        override fun onResourceReady(
                            resource: Bitmap,
                            transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?
                        ) {

                            val paint = Paint()
                            paint.isAntiAlias = true
                            paint.isFilterBitmap = true
                            paint.isDither = true

                            boardSketch?.run {
                                matrix?.let { floats ->
                                    xLeft = floats[0]
                                    yTop = floats[1]
                                }
                            }

                            val scaledWidth = resource.width / scaleX
                            val scaledHeight = resource.height / scaleY

                            val scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(resource, scaledWidth.toInt(), scaledHeight.toInt(), true)

                            val src = Rect(xLeft.toInt(), yTop.toInt(), scaledBitmap.width, scaledBitmap.height)
                            val dest = Rect(xLeft.toInt(), yTop.toInt(), scaledBitmap.width, scaledBitmap.height)

                            canvas.drawBitmap(resource, src, dest, paint)
                            return it.resume(Unit)
                        }

                        override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {
                            // this is called when imageView is cleared on lifecycle call or for
                            // some other reason.
                            // if you are referencing the bitmap somewhere else too other than this imageView
                            // clear it here as you can no longer have the bitmap
                        }
                    })
            }
        }
    }
```

And below is the code for drawing text on the canvas:

**Text on the canvas**

```
private fun drawTextOnCanvas(sketch: BoardSketch, extraCanvas: Canvas, paint: Paint) {
     
        var xPosition = 16F
        var yPosition = 16F
        var scaleX = 1.0F
        var scaleY = 1.0F

        sketch.matrix?.let {
            xPosition = it[0]
            yPosition = it[1]
            scaleX = it[2]
            scaleY = it[3]
        }

        paint.textScaleX = scaleX
        val textSize = sketch.size ?: AppConstants.DEFAULT_TEXT_SIZE_FOR_ANDROID
        val paintScaledTextSize = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, textSize, resources.displayMetrics)
        paint.textSize = paintScaledTextSize
        extraCanvas.drawText(sketch.data, xPosition, yPosition, paint)
    }
```

However, the saved pdf is neither reflecting proper x, y positions of the images and texts nor does it is showing proper scale factors.

Maybe we are using the wrong methods or our math calculation is wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR:

Use `scaleX` and `scaleY` in `override` of `Glide` to load the image as per our scale factor. Once the image is loaded as per the scale factor, use x and y positions acquired from `view.locationOnScreen` to draw it on the `Canvas`.

**Uploaded on the device:**

[image]

**Saved pdf:**

[image]

**Uploading to Firebase**

```
private fun actionUpEvent(view: View, tag: String, event: MotionEvent) {
        
        val arrayListOfPairs = arrayListOf(Pair(event.x, event.y))
        saveCoordinates(tag, arrayListOfPairs)

        //Absolute position of the view (image or text view) on screen
        val viewLocationOnScreen = IntArray(2)
        view.getLocationOnScreen(viewLocationOnScreen)
        val viewXOnScreen = viewLocationOnScreen[0]
        val viewYOnScreen = viewLocationOnScreen[1]

        //Absolute canvas (container of image and text) position on screen 
        val boardWindowXOnScreen = viewModel.boardXOnScreen 
        val boardWindowYOnScreen = viewModel.boardYOnScreen
 
        //Image and text x, y distance in canvas
        val viewXOnCanvas = viewXOnScreen - boardWindowXOnScreen
        val viewYOnCanvas = viewYOnScreen - boardWindowYOnScreen

        //if for an X size, view.x is view.x, then what will it be for Y size
        matrix = arrayListOf(
                    viewModel.getServerX(view.x),
                    viewModel.getServerY(view.y),
                    viewModel.getServerScaleXtoSend(view.scaleX),
                    viewModel.getServerScaleYtoSend(view.scaleY)
                )
    
                
                if (view is ImageView) {
                    rect = arrayListOf(
                        viewModel.getServerX(viewXOnCanvas.toFloat()),
                        viewModel.getServerY(viewYOnCanvas.toFloat()),
                        view.width.toFloat(),
                        view.height.toFloat()
                    )
                } else if (view is TextView) {
                    val rectBound = Rect()
                    val textPaint = view.paint
                    textPaint.getTextBounds(data, 0, data.length, rectBound)
                    val textViewBoundHeight = rectBound.height()
                    val textViewBoundWidth = rectBound.width()
                    val lineHeight = view.lineCount * view.lineHeight
                    view.measure(0,0)
                    val measuredWidth = view.measuredWidth
                    val measuredHeight = view.measuredHeight
                    rect = arrayListOf(
                        viewModel.getServerX(viewXOnCanvas.toFloat()),
                        viewModel.getServerY((viewYOnCanvas + textViewBoundHeight).toFloat()),
                        textViewBoundWidth.toFloat(),
                        measuredHeight.toFloat()
                    )
                }

        sendPointsToServer(matrix, rect)
        view.clipBounds
    }
```

**Bitmap On Canvas**

```
private suspend fun drawBitmapOnCanvas(
        canvas: Canvas,
        uriStringPath: String,
        firebaseData: FirebaseData? = null
    ) {
        if (uriStringPath.isEmpty()) {
            return
        } else {
            return suspendCoroutine {
                var viewX = 0f
                var viewY = 0f
                var scaleX = 1F
                var scaleY = 1F
                var xLocationOnScreen = viewX
                var yLocationOnScreen = viewY
                var viewOriginalWidth: Int = canvas.width
                var viewOriginalHeight: Int = canvas.height

                firebaseData?.matrix?.let { matrix ->
                    viewX = matrix[0]
                    viewY = matrix[1]
                    scaleX = matrix[2]
                    scaleY = matrix[3]
                }

                firebaseData?.rect?.let { rect ->
                    xLocationOnScreen = rect[0]
                    yLocationOnScreen = rect[1]
                    viewOriginalWidth = rect[2].toInt()
                    viewOriginalHeight = rect[3].toInt()
                }

                val viewScaledWidth: Float = viewOriginalWidth * scaleX
                val viewScaledHeight: Float = viewOriginalHeight * scaleY

                Glide.with(this)
                    .asBitmap()
                    .override(viewScaledWidth.toInt(), viewScaledHeight.toInt())
                    .load(uriStringPath)
                    .into(object : CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
                        override fun onResourceReady(
                            resource: Bitmap,
                            transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?
                        ) {

                            val paint = Paint()
                            paint.isAntiAlias = true
                            paint.isFilterBitmap = true
                            paint.isDither = true                            

                                                        
                            canvas.drawBitmap(resource, xLocationOnScreen, yLocationOnScreen, null)

                            return it.resume(Unit)
                        }

                        override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {
                            // this is called when imageView is cleared on lifecycle call or for
                            // some other reason.
                            // if you are referencing the bitmap somewhere else too other than this imageView
                            // clear it here as you can no longer have the bitmap
                        }
                    })
            }
        }
    }
```

**Text On Canvas**

```
private fun drawTextOnCanvas(firebaseData: FirebaseData, extraCanvas: Canvas, paint: Paint) {
        
        val textPaint = paint.apply {
            style = Paint.Style.FILL
        }
        var viewX = 16F
        var viewY = 16F
        var scaleX = 1.0F
        var scaleY = 1.0F
        var viewXOnCanvas = 16F
        var viewYOnCanvas = 16F
        var width = firebaseData.data.length //firebaseData.data is a string.
        var height = scaleY

        firebaseData.matrix?.let {
            viewX = it[0]
            viewY = it[1]
            scaleX = it[2]
            scaleY = it[3]
        }

        firebaseData.rect?.let {
            viewXOnCanvas = it[0]
            viewYOnCanvas = it[1]
            width = it[2].toInt()
            height = it[3]
        }

        val textSize = firebaseData.size ?: AppConstants.DEFAULT_TEXT_SIZE_FOR_ANDROID

        val paintScaledTextSize = TypedValue.applyDimension(
            TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,
            textSize,
            resources.displayMetrics
        )

        textPaint.textSize = paintScaledTextSize * scaleX

        val textBounds = Rect()
        textPaint.getTextBounds(firebaseData.data, 0, firebaseData.data.length, textBounds)

        //TODO: Need to use StaticLayout to support multiline text.

        extraCanvas.drawText(firebaseData.data, viewXOnCanvas, viewYOnCanvas, textPaint)
    }
```